# HP EliteBook 8570p webcam and speakers with docking station

Tags: docking-station, hp-elitebook

Just got an HP EliteBook 8570p with a docking station. Hooked up 2 monitors, mouse, USB webcam, speakers and USB keyboard to the docking station. The monitors, keyboard and mouse all work well but the webcam (with built in mic) and speakers are not working.

Is there a Windows 7 setting/config that needs to be changed to make the webcam/mic/speaker go to the ones on the docking station when it's docked?

Comment: have you changed the default player for sound and default video in (webcam) as well as default mic in the control panel; sounds section?

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be between the keyboard and the chair.

1. The webcam/mic needed a reboot to get it working.
2. Speakers had been plugged in to the mic instead of speaker plug (not by me).